# Getting energy momentum tensor from $L =( 1/2)φ(∂^2 + m^2)φ$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am studying QFT with Schwartz’s textbook and solving problem 3.2.

But I somehow getting struggled with differentiating the given lagrangian

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\phi(\Box +m^2)\phi$

I know that I need to get $$T^{\mu\nu} =\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}-g^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$$ but I cannot differentiate the first term which gives me $\frac{\partial}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}(\frac{1}{2}\phi\partial^\mu\partial_\mu\phi + \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2)$
$=(1/2) \frac{\partial}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}(\partial^\mu(\phi\partial_\mu\phi))-\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi+m^2\phi^2)$

And I cannot get into next steps… could you help differentiating it?

Comment: Try partially integrating the kinetic term before differentiating that (assuming vanishing at boundary) will nit change the classic result but will maybe make it easier to see what is going on

Comment: The Lagrangian is always(?) interpreted as a functional of the fields and their first derivatives, $\mathcal L = \mathcal L(\phi_i, \partial_\mu \phi_i)$. So, first you should integrate by parts to get your Lagrangian which should be $\mathcal L = - \tfrac 1 2 (\partial_\mu \phi) (\partial^\mu \phi) + \tfrac 1 2 m \phi^2$. Then you treat $\partial_\mu \phi$ and $\phi$ like two different variables $x,y$ when taking the partial derivative of the Lagrangian.

Comment: @Myridium:  You can have higher derivatives in a classical Lagrangian, but the Euler-Lagrange equations have to account for them.  The full Euler-Lagrange equations are something like$$0 = \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi} - \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta (\partial_\mu \phi)} \right) +  \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \left( \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta (\partial_\mu  \partial_\nu \phi)} \right) - \, + ...$$Not sure how this affects the canonical stress-energy, but I wouldn't be surprised if those results change as well.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I was buried down in the idea of differentiating it.
$\int d^4x\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\phi\partial^\mu\phi -\int \frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi + \int\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$
which the first term of the RHS vanishes in infinite. Thanks for everyone!

Comment: @JLee it's not your fault. Partial differentiation is a shorthand notation. The partial derivative $\partial f / \partial x$ is shorthand for $\mathrm d f / \mathrm d \lambda$ where $\lambda$ parameterises a path in the coordinate space. This path is not uniquely determined, however. It depends on the choice of coordinates. One always assumes a certain set of coordinates implicitly. When it comes to Lagrangians, the phrase $\partial \mathcal L / \partial(\partial_\mu \phi)$ is nonsense without further context. The context is that $\mathcal L \equiv \mathcal L(\phi_i, \partial_\mu \phi_i)$.

Comment: @JLee for a concrete example, draw two 2D coordinate system grids: one with the $y$ axis vertical (orthogonal coordinate system), and the other with the $y$ axis slanted (affine coordinate system). Now ask what is $\partial f / \partial x$ in each of the two spaces. It is different in either one, even though the coordinate function $x$ is the same in both spaces! One must always specify what they are holding constant while they take a partial derivative w.r.t. $x$. I.e. one must constrain the path. It is always just assumed that $\partial f(x,y,z)/\partial x$ should hold $y,z$ constant.